# Is it possible to switch an SD card from one Pi or another with an OS already set up?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, pi-3, raspbian-jessie, software-compatibility

I am about to upgrade a web server from pi2b to pi3b. I would like to know if I can take the SD card as it is from the Pi2b and use It in the pi3b, and the higher performance options for the pi3b be recognized? I really don't want to start a fresh install for the pi3b and transfer the Web site if I don't have to. Distro is raspbian Jessie. Thanks yall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - provided the OS is new enough. You don't say what OS you are using. Assuming Raspbian Jessie you need kernel `4.1.18` or later.

To be on the safe side to a `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get upgrade` first.

I would recommend `sudo apt-get dist-update` which will get the latest, released a few days ago. This has some useful additions, but you will need to install extra packages to get all of these see https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/#another-update-raspbian

Comment: thank you. And I edited the post to reflect accurate OS. So far as I know it's got the recent update.